# Guess the output. (Declaration/ initialization of a character array)

Tags: c++

Here is a piece of code. I'm using g++

```
void initialize(int p, char a[], char b[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<6*p;i++)
    {
        a[i]='-';
        b[i]='-';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int p=9;
    char a[2*p],b[4*p];
    initialize(p,a,b);
    cout<<a<<endl<<b<<endl;
}
```

Here, the way a and b are declared... they should be of size 18 and 36 respectively. But they aren't as seen in the output. What is happening?

```
Output:
------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initialising far outside the bounds of the memory you have allocated for `a` and `b`

You need to do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2*p; ++i) {
    a[i]='-';
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4*p; ++i) {
    b[i]='-';
}
```

Assigning to memory outside of the memory you own could do literally anything. Like send a fax to your dog.

Comment: I do like the idea of faxing my dog.

Comment: When initializing in bounds, it shows garbage values for some more space beyond it. That is why.

Comment: @Nikhil: Garbage beyond it is due to null-termination. See raj raj's answer or my own for more info

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[2*p] will have 2*9=18 characters max.
char b[4*p] will have 4*9=36 characters max.
```

initialize creates 6*9 = 54 characters but each object accepts within its own limit. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to initialize a with 18, b with 36 'dashes'. But then b had garbage values after 36th dash that looked like �

Comment: I can't see those in my browser :|

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<6*p;i++)
```

Treats the array size as `6*p` where in the example `p==9`. So your loop treats the array size as 54.

But array `a` has only 18 elements so your initialisation is overflowing this array.

Array `b` has only 36 elements so your initialisation is overflowing this array as well.

Overflowing an array will write to memory that you probably do not intend to write to, which can cause all sorts of bugs...

You would be better to use a function like. Also do you need to **NULL-terminate** your strings?

```
void initialize(char a[], size_t aSize, char b[], size_t bSize)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < aSize-1; i++)
        a[i]='-';
    for(i = 0; i < bSize-1; i++)
        b[i]='-';

    // I think you need to NULL terminate....
    a[aSize-1] = '\0';
    b[bSize-1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    int p=9;
    char a[2*p],b[4*p];
    initialize(a, sizeof(a), b, sizeof(b));

    std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or even more generically in you `main()` function if you ever use arrays that are *not* of type `char`...

```
initialize(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
```

Or even, to initialise the arrays just use  [***memset()***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) and then you won't need the function `initialize()` :)

E.g.

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int p=9;
    char a[2*p],b[4*p];

    memset(a, '-', sizeof(a)-1);
    a[sizeof(a)-1] == '\0';
    memset(b, '-', sizeof(b)-1);
    b[sizeof(b)-1] == '\0';

    std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The other thing I just though of was "are you **NULL-terminating** your strings? I've changed the above examples to cater for that, otherwise when printing the string the print function won't know where to stop!

Yet another option might also be [***std::fill()***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) or [***std::fill_n()***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>    // std::fill

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p=9;
    char a[2*p],b[4*p];

    std::fill_n(a, sizeof(a)-1, '-');
    a[sizeof(a)-1] = '\0';

    std::fill_n(b, sizeof(b)-1, '-');
    b[sizeof(b)-1] = '\0';

    std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output that you get is just because you don't null terminate the strings. You may not be getting the same output that you got now, if you put your code in some other way. It's just that you went on initializing the arrays out of bound and somehow both arrays lie near each other and `cout` looked for next `'\0'` till where it printed.

Just null-terminate the array and everything is fine then.

Comment: raj, he has array overflow issues as well, it's not just null termination that is causing problems

Comment: Yes, but he gets such lengthy outputs because of not terminating it, right? And, accessing arrays out of bounds is never recommended.

Comment: Yes, the null-termination is producing the length errors, but `Just null-terminate the array and everything is fine then.` isn't quite right, because he still has a potentially rather nasty bug, which isn't fine :)

Comment: Jimbo, you are right. And i guess Nikhil(the one who asked this question) already knows it and he just experimenting out things. So, i didn't mention that part.